# Azure App Insights Failures not loading in the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

In the past week or so I have started seeing an issue within Azure when I try to view the "Failures" blade of the Application Insights resource for our app. It used to work absolutely fine and now it just shows "not found" in small black text on the page where the content used to be.

For clarity this is the view I am talking about:

[image]

All of the tabs from the "Investigate" section of the side bar do the same thing. If I go to logs I can see everything when searching for it. Is anyone else experiencing the same issue or knows how to fix this?

Comment: It's fine at my side. Can you please press F12 button and see the request/response details from the browser? It might a temp issue or issue related to some regions.

Comment: This is happening on my account all of a sudden - it's been a few days....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to have resolved itself overnight after a few days of not working. Maybe it was region specific as @IvanYang said above. We are using the UK South region.

Comment: I am getting a very similar issue with any page under the "Investigate" section in UK South showing "Not found".